# How to use iframe in ng-bind-html in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

This is my controller where i get data in JSON form, here i want to bind iframe but i am not able to work it out, so please help me out , any suggestion would be appreciated , thank in advance

```
 angular.module('myApp.view2.controllers',[]).
        controller('mediacontroller',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
            $http({
             method:"GET",
             url :"../app/media.php"
            }).then(function mySuccess(response){
                    var string = '';
                    var media_id = 0;
                    var media ;
                    var file ;
                    string = '<table border=1><thead><tr><th colspan="4">Media detail</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
                    angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {

                        if(media_id===0){
                            media_id = 1;
                            string+='<tr><td class="mediatd">'+value.id+'</td><td class="mediatd">'+value.title+'</td><td class="mediatd">'+value.description+'</td></tr>';
                            string+='<tr><td class="mediatd">Category</td><td class="mediatd">Media</td><td class="mediatd">Sequence</td></tr>';

                        }else if (media_id!==value.id){
                            media_id = value.id;
                            string+='<tr><td class="mediatd">'+value.id+'</td><td class="mediatd">'+value.title+'</td><td class="mediatd">'+value.description+'</td></tr>';
                             string+='<tr><td class="mediatd">Category</td><td class="mediatd">Media</td><td class="mediatd">Sequence</td></tr>';
                        }
                        if(value.category==0){
                              media = 'image';
                              file = '<img src="http://localhost/mm2asia/img/media&news/media/'+value.media+'" style="height:100px; width:120px;" alt="">';
                        }else{
                              media = 'video';
                              file = '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+value.media+'" ></iframe>';
                        }
                        string+='<tr><td>'+media+'</td><td>'+file+'</td><td>'+value.rearrange+'</td></tr>';
                        //console.log('<tr><td>'+value.id+'</td><td>'+value.title+'</td><td>'+value.description+'</td></tr>');
                    });
                    string += '</tbody></table>';
                    //console.log(string);
                    $scope.myHTML=string;
                }, function myError(response){
                    var string = '';
                    string = response.statusText;
                    $scope.myHTML=string;
            });

}]);
```

Here my view

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="mediacontroller">   
      <div ng-bind-html="myHTML"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to bind html.  Why don't you use `ng-switch` to toggle which content should be on the page and use actual html markup instead of strings.

Comment: ok @Malkus , I'll try this , thank you for your time and valuable suggestion:)